# VueJS app is blank

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs2

I have started vueJS app cloning this repo https://github.com/auth0-blog/vue-jwt-authentication. I have developed with that for few days and developed some pages with that. Later realized that it was Vue1.0. I then used https://github.com/vuejs/vue-migration-helper and migrated to vue 2.0. I have fixed all the errors one by one.

Now when I run the app, it just does not show any error but it was empty.
I dont even get any errors in either browser console or in npm terminal. 
In the Inspect element, `<div id="app"></div>` was empty. Someone please take some time. I have the code in this repo here. https://bitbucket.org/AswinKP/vuesample. I am sharing the entire repo because I cant just figure out where I am making a mistake.

I have researched for this and cant find any such issues. 
I am a beginner in vue js and I am struggling in this for last two days. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nothing immediately jumps out at me as wrong. Does it work with the standalone build? Try adding the following to your `webpack.config.js` : `resolve: {
  alias: {
    'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js'
  }
}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several errors. First the repo can't compile at all.

in index.js:8 and :37
the file `components/IncidentTrendI7.vue` doesn't exist, simply remove these two lines.

and the `build.js` isn't included in your `index.html`, add `<script src="build/build.js"></script>` manually in your `index.html`

The last one is your root component. You need a render function to render your app in Vue 2.0 (or a template if you use the standalone build, but the runtime-only version is preferred), so the root component in your `index.js` will look like:

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
  components: { App }
})
```

Comment: Sorry for `IncidentTrendI7.vue` . I had some private code in that. So I removed in the last minute while pushing to the sample repo. Thank you for taking your time..

Comment: Never heard that one would need `build.js` in the index.html. I think this hint is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Face the same issue i solved it my adding base url to routerwebhistory by default its point to  root of your folder

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/vue/dist/' : '/'
}

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory('/vue/dist'),
  routes,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
import Home from './components/Home.vue'
```

to:

```
import Home from '@/components/Home'
```

I solved the same problem like this.

Answer (score 0):

With new vue-cli V3 you can customize your settings for the build-process in file

> vue.config.js

You can add "pages"-object. With this settings (applied to the default file-structure), I got the effect "no error, blank Page".

> entry:'src/main.js'

seems not to work in dev-mode, even build-mode was working

```
pages: {
  index: {
    // entry for the page
    entry: 'src/main.js',
    // the source template
    template: 'public/index.html',
    // output as dist/index.html
    filename: 'customname.html',
    // when using title option,
    // template title tag needs to be <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %</title>
    title: 'Print Label'
      }
```